# Javascript Parse JSON lookalike

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a string that looks eerily like json:

```
columns: [
  {
    allowNull: false,
    autoEnterSubType: 0,
    autoEnterType: 2,
    creationOrderIndex: 0,
    dataType: 4,
    databaseSequenceName: "seq_admintraties_adminratie_id",
    flags: 1,
    name: "administratie_id"
  },
  {
    allowNull: true,
    creationOrderIndex: 4,
    dataType: 12,
    length: 50,
    name: "database_naam"
  },
  {
    allowNull: true,
    creationOrderIndex: 1,
    dataType: 12,
    length: 50,
    name: "naam"
  },
  {
    allowNull: true,
    creationOrderIndex: 2,
    dataType: 12,
    length: 50,
    name: "omschrijving"
  },
  {
    allowNull: true,
    creationOrderIndex: 3,
    dataType: 12,
    length: 50,
    name: "organisatie_naam"
  }
],
name: "administraties",
tableType: 0
```

but isn't

I need to parse it with javascript, but I don't want to go through the splitting stuff, because I feel it can be done in an easier way.

Does any of you have a suggestion on how to approach this?

Comment: `eval` is the easiest way to parse this... like it or not

Answer (score 0):

The string you have provided is not in valid format. It needs to be corrected. All keys must be enclosed with double quotes and whole string must be enclosed with parentheses.

I have corrected part of your input string so you can get idea,

```
{
  "columns":[
    {
      "allowNull":false,
      "autoEnterSubType":0,
      "autoEnterType":2
    },
    {
      "allowNull":true,
      "creationOrderIndex":4
    }
  ],
  "name":"administraties",
  "tableType":0
}
```

You can use below site to validate any json string :

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

use this regular expression to convert your string in json :

```
var str   = 'your_string';
var regex = /^[^"]([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+/;
str = str.replace(regex, "$&");

str = "{" + str + "}";
```